# Missing some widgets in LinearLayout's vertical orientation unlike horizontal orientation

Tags: android, android-layout

Horizontal orientation has six icons.

[image: Horizontal Orientation]

But when it moved to vertical, it also should be six (2 in next line).

[image]

how should I do with my linear layout ?

Comment: Create different layouts one for landscape and one for portrait mode.

Comment: Have you added scroll view to your main layout?? if not, then use horizontal scroll view

Comment: You can use weight or relative layout.

Comment: of cuz Lokesh, Scroll View is my parent layout and then Linear layout is within the scroll view.

Comment: Kanwaljit Singh, I don't think so.